# Scala and JMM: number types performance

Tags: scala, java-memory-model

I'm new in Scala and don't understand some base things.

Scala does not contains primitives. Hence int, short and other "simple" number types are objects. So, according to JMM, they are not located at stack and subject to cleaning by GB.  Cleaning by GB may be too expensive for some cases.

So I don't clearly understand, why Scala is considered faster than Java (in which primitives located in stack).

Comment: You are confusing the language with the runtime, at the language level **Scala** only has objects; no primitives. - However, once the code is compiled to the target platform _(remember **Scala** can be used on other runtimes other than the JVM)_ the compiler is free to use primitives and do any other optimization it wants . - _"So I don't clearly understand, why Scala is considered faster than Java"_ I can think of multiple reasons to prefer **Scala** over **Java**, being faster is neither of them; from where do you take that afirmation?

Comment: What does the *Java* Memory Model have to do with *Scala*, a completely different programming language?

Comment: @JörgWMittag the JMM (Java Memory Model) concerns the runtime, the JVM, so it has a few things to do with Scala. See: http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/ But yes, it might be a bit of a stretch to say that this question touches that much on the JMM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Scala does not contains primitives. Hence int, short and other "simple" number types are objects.

That is correct.

> So, according to JMM,

The Java Memory Model is for *Java*. It is completely irrelevant to Scala.

> they are not located at stack and subject to cleaning by GB.  Cleaning by GB may be too expensive for some cases.

There is no such thing as a "stack" in Scala. The [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/) only mentions the term "stack" in very few places, and none of them have anything to do with `Int`s:

- In [section 1 *Lexical Syntax*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html), [subsection 1.6 *XML mode*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/01-lexical-syntax.html#xml-mode), it is said that because XML literals and Scala code can be arbitrarily nested, the parser has to use a stack data structure to keep track of the context.
- In [section 7 *Implicits*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html), subsection [7.2 *Implicit parameters*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#implicit-parameters), it is said that to prevent an infinite recursion when searching for implicit, the compiler keeps a stack of "open types", which are types that it is currently searching an implicit for.
- In [section 6 *Expressions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html), [subsection 6.6 *Function Applications*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications), there is the following statement, specifying Proper Direct Tail Recursion:

  > A function application usually allocates a new frame on the program's run-time stack. However, if a local method or a final method calls itself as its last action, the call is executed using the stack-frame of the caller.
- In [section 6 *Expressions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html), [subsection 6.20 *Return Expressions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#return-expressions), there is the following statement about *one possible implementation strategy* for non-local returns from nested functions:

  > Returning from the method from within a nested function may be implemented by throwing and catching a `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl`. Any exception catches between the point of return and the enclosing methods might see and catch that exception. A key comparison makes sure that this exception is only caught by the method instance which is terminated by the return.
  >
  > If the return expression is itself part of an anonymous function, it is possible that the enclosing method *m* has already returned before the return expression is executed. In that case, the thrown `scala.runtime.NonLocalReturnControl` will not be caught, and will propagate up the call stack.

Of these 4 instances, the first 2 clearly *do not* refer to the concept of a call stack but rather to the generic computer science data structure. The 4th one is only an example of a possible implementation strategy ("Returning from the method from within a nested function **may** be implemented by […]"). Only the 3rd one is actually relevant, as it indeed talks about a call stack. However, it does not say anything about allocating `Int`s, and it explicitly leaves the door open to alternative implementations as well, by stating that "usually" function application leads to allocation of a stack frame, but doesn't have to.

> So I don't clearly understand, why Scala is considered faster than Java (in which primitives located in stack).

Actually, there is nothing in the Java Language Specification either that says that primitives are located on the stack. In fact, the Java Language Specification does not mandate the existence of a stack at all. It would be perfectly legal to implement Java without a stack.

There are exactly *zero* occurrences of the term "stack" in [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/). There *are* a couple of mentions of the term "heap", but *only* in the compound term "heap pollution", which is simply a word describing a certain flaw in the type system, but does not necessarily require a heap, and does not mandate a heap.

And none of these mentions of "heap pollution" have anything to do with primitives.

Note that, when I say that the Scala Language Specification says nothing about stacks or heaps or how `Int`s are allocated, that is actually really important. *Because* the SLS doesn't say anything, implementors are allowed to do whatever they want, *including* making `Int`s primitive and allocating them on the stack.

And that is exactly what most Scala implementations do. The (now-defunct) Scala.NET implemented `scala.Int` as a .NET `System.Int32`. [Scala-native](https://scala-native.readthedocs.io/) implements `scala.Int` as a C `int32_t`. [Scala.js](https://scala-js.org/) implements `scala.Int` as an ECMAScript `number`. And [Scala-JVM](https://github.com/scala/scala/) implements `scala.Int` as a JVM `int`.

If you check out the source code of `scala.Int` in the Scala-JVM repository ([`src/library/scala/Int.scala`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/Int.scala)), you will find that it is actually empty! More precisely, it only contains [documentation](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html) and declarations, but no definitions or implementations. Also, the class is marked `final` (meaning it can't be inherited from) and `abstract` (meaning it must be inherited from in order to provide overrides for the missing implementations), which is a contradiction.

How does this work? Well, the compiler knows what an `Int` is and how it works, and it simply generates the correct code for dealing with a JVM `int`. So, when it sees a call to `scala.Int.+`, it knows that instead it must generate an [`iadd` bytecode instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se16/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.iadd). Likewise, Scala-native will just generate the native integer addition instructions, and so on.

In other words, `Int`s are *semantically defined* as objects, but they are actually *pragmatically implemented* as primitives.

This is a general rule of how language specifications work: typically, they only describe what the result is that the programmer sees, but they leave it open to the implementor how to actually achieve that result. So, the SLS specifies that an `Int` must *look* as if it actually *were* an object, but there is nothing that says it actually has to *be* one.

Comment: Thank you for so mush detailed answer! Something became more clearly for me.

Answer (score 2):

They are handled the same way that Java handles those types, they're only boxed when strictly necessary. The details on how and when they are boxed may differ, but the compiler uses a primitive representation if it can do so. Here's what the docs say (this is just for `Int`, but it applies to other "primitive" types too):

> Int, a 32-bit signed integer (equivalent to Java's int primitive type) is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. **Instances of Int are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system.**
>
> There is an implicit conversion from scala.Int => scala.runtime.RichInt which provides useful non-primitive operations.
>
> https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/Int.html

The main difference, really, is that there *aren't* two separate types, like in Java, to represent the boxed and unboxed representations — both get the same `Int` type, whereas Java has `int` and `Integer`.

Comment: "Instances of Int are not represented by an object in the underlying runtime system."  I should have seen this part of documentation before asking question. Thank you!